# Orbeon Form Builder - Loading remote logged in user's windows user name

Tags: orbeon

I have a form created using Orbeon Form Builder and my requirement is to display the windows user name of the remotely logged in user in a label control. Any coding samples or suggestions please...? need help

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged into the Orbeon Forms web app, then you can access the user's username with the `xxf:username()` function in XPath. You can find more on this, and related functions, in the [HTTP functions documentation](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-http.html).

Comment: Thank you @avernet Can I know where to add `xxf:username()`, is to the initial value of the label control?

Comment: At least using "just" Form Builder, you can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37122482/5295.