# Orbeon - HTTP Headers

Tags: orbeon

I have a form created by Form Builder and I want to display the values of request headers in a label control, could I please know where to add `xxf:get-request-header()`? Is it on the initial value box of the control and are there configurations I need to make in the `properties-local.xml` file in order to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "label control"? Are you referring to the label of a control, like an input field?

Comment: yes, what I meant was a control that we add from tool box such as a Input Filed or a Text Output.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the clarification, and I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *formulas*, and more specifically a *calculated value* to set the value of a field, but at this point Form Builder doesn't support setting the label of a field using a formula.

If possible, I'd recommend you use a *Calculated Value* value field, and show the value somewhere else in the form.